# What really limits off-chip I/O? Capacitance or Inductance?

Tags: communication, wire, transmission-line, io

To my understanding, the crucial limiting factor for off-chip I/O is bondwire inductance, something that seeks to be minimized with BGA, flip-chip bonding etc.

The rationale is that an RC wire model is only valid for low frequencies where \$ f < \frac{R}{2\pi L}\$. References:

1. https://people.engr.tamu.edu/spalermo/ecen689/lecture1_ee720_intro.pdf , slide 10
2. https://people.engr.tamu.edu/spalermo/ecen689/lecture2_ee720_channels.pdf , slides 7, 8, 20

On-chip, we get away with simple RC-models because L is negligible compared to R if we consider frequencies up to a few GHz. But this is not the case for bondwires or PCB traces.

Now there is an interesting review paper [Attojoule Optoelectronics for Low-Energy Information Processing and Communications - a Tutorial Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05510) from David Miller (Stanford) which explains the limits of electrical communication and that the answer to this is optical communication (even for low distance links -- for large distance links this is obvious due to large losses in electrical lines).

In his whole 54-page paper, the word *inductance* does not appear a single time. His argument is based solely on the energy to charge a wire capacitance to a certain voltage (\$E=CV^2\$). This requires assuming an RC wire model and not an LC or RLGC model.

- Why is that?
- Why does Miller completely ignore inductance for his general (not only IC) discussion when the RC model is only valid for low frequencies?
- What is now actually limiting the limiting factor for off-chip I/O: capacitance or inductance?

Comment: both. track impedance with capacitance will slow down the risetime of the signal. track inductance with impedance will slow down charging up the capacitance slowing the risetime. the RLC of a trace creates a transmission line with the pcb  which has a finite bandwidth and impacts signal quality (ringing)

Comment: The title and question are too vague to answer. What limits are you interested in? Bandwidth? Then consider inductance. But the referenced paper appears (from "attojoule" in the title, to be concerned about something entirely different ... energy efficiency, hence focussing on RC (in which it is the R that absorbs energy irreversibly)

Comment: I am trying to reconcile my previous understanding of "off-chip I/O is limited by bondwires" with Miller's notion of "off-chip I/O is limited by wire capacitance". Energy vs. bandwidth could be the answer to that. But for dynamic energy consumption, R doesn't matter. Energy is always CV^2. But we also have energy due to inductance ~LI^2. It seems Miller assumes L=0. Why?

Comment: Furthermore, even if we talk about the energy efficiency: Given his discussion on increased data rate demands, it would not make sense to assume very slow speeds. As data rates (bit/s) increases, so must the signal frequency. It wouldn't make sense to discuss why optical communication is the solution assuming data rate = 1b/s. So I think I am interested in the limit of energy efficiency subject to datarate("bandwidth") >>G/s datarates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One limiting factor for getting data off chip is impedance. I worked on a microwave divider chip a while ago, and the single-ended output terminal consisted of two adjacent pins for signal, flanked by two further pins for local ground, in an effort to get the impedance of the transmission line from chip to PCB down to something within spitting distance of a practical 50Ω. The requirement was high power delivered to the load.

High speed serial links like HDMI, SATA  etc use differential signalling and low swing at the receiver, so they can launch currents into practical impedances while allowing the chip to PCB path to be fairly high impedance. The requirement is high speed, with only sufficient power for good quality reception.

Another similar but distinct factor is charging the capacitance of the remote node. Why does Miller ignore inductance? He regards inductance as a complicating factor, which can in theory be eliminated by using a suitable geometry. It's a common simplification in this sort of analysis, choose a best case, and compute a lower bound for it. The actual performance will always be worse than this, due to the factors you have ignored.